# React + Meteor + Harmony?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, meteorite

I would like to use Meteor with React and Harmony (Traceur).

I've added both the "react" and "harmony" package.

```
mrt add react
mrt add harmony
```

However, it does not quite work. The react JSX transformer runs for the `.jsx`. However, the traceur transform does not run for the resulting files.

Also, the [react blog](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html) mention something about a harmony flag which I am unsure how to set.

Comment: You'll probably have to create your own package that combines the two.

Comment: does it work if you call your files like "a.next.jsx"?

Comment: Harmony flag is Node thing, you can simply add `--harmony` after node command to support more ES6 features.